# using log as a parameter in a function in r

Tags: r

What does it mean If we use `log` in a function in r.

```
x.spec<-spectrum(datalist,log=c("no"))
```

in this example the `spectrum` function has no parameter like `log`, but we use it and we can see the difference if we use it or not. What does `log=c("no")` exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an argument of `plot.spec` and it gets passed through to it via the `...` in the `spectrum` function - it first passes the arbitrary params encoded in `...` to `spec.pgram`, which then passes it to `plot.spec`, which in turn has a `log` param and interprets it appropriately.

See `?plot.spec` for usage details of that argument.